# how can i make text wrapping in responsive div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm building a site with Bootsrap and using grid system totally. I got a problem with long text.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">
    LONGTEXTHERELONGTEXTHERELONGTEXTHERE
    </div>
</div>
```

You see, I don't know the real width size, so I can't do text wrapping in that div. Can I not do text wrapping without fixed width size?
I tried:

```
 word-wrap:break-word;
 white-space:initial;
 white-space:normal;
```

but these things works with fixed width size.

Comment: Why do you say that `word-wrap:break-word;` is not working? https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/v7q29x6k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `word-wrap: break-word;` with `display: table-cell;`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.col-xs-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    LONGTEXTHERELONGTEXTHERELONGTEXTHERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i really don't know how im still getting overflow.its work here but dont work in my project.im trying to make comments part so i have alot of responsive div.but all divs in container and col-md-9.i just made .text-wrap class and added ur codes to inside of it.but i still have same problem

Comment: @erginduran Therefore your code has some peculiarity. Please add your code to the answer or give us the link on your webpage.

Answer (score 4):

This CSS should do what you need:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! But long text is still going overflow.i think this things is not working without fixed width :/ but my div's width size is col-md-9/responsive so still cannot wrap it

Comment: If the col-md-9 is wider than the word, it still wont wrap. It would only wrap when it gets to the end of the div, even with the word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: If you want it to wrap before it reaches the end of the div, it would have to have a specific width that was lower than the width of the word.

Comment: check other answers.its work with word-wrap tag but its not work with col-md-9 and in my project its realy interesting situation

Comment: Strange. There could be some other CSS conflicting on that specific (.col-md-9) class.

Answer (score 0):

You mean long words, don't you? (Long text will always break automatically at word ends)

`word-wrap: break-word;` does the trick...